# SQL Server CASE inside where clause not working for NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What I want is when `@AddressCode` is null then simply execute

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Addresses
WHERE
    1= 1
```

If @AddressCode is not NULL then execute

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Addresses
WHERE
    1= 1 AND @AddressCode=Addresses.AddressCode
```

How can I achieve this ... I tried query below and its not working for Address with `NULL` value or when `@AddressCode is NULL` .... (Addresses is just an imaginary table name)

```
Declare @AddressCode varchar(20)
Set @AddressCode=NULL

SELECT
    *
FROM
    Addresses
WHERE
    1= 1
    AND
    CASE @AddressCode
        WHEN NULL
        THEN Addresses.AddressCode
        ELSE @AddressCode
    END =Addresses.AddressCode
```

I tried hard but am not able to make it ... I know i can write IF statement and write individual select statement but don't want to do that as i have lots of such criteria as `@AddressCode` :(

Comment: ISNULL is your friend here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Addresses
WHERE
    (@AddressCode IS NULL OR Addresses.AddressCode = @AddressCode)
```

Comment: If address code is indexed you would need to use `RECOMPILE` with this to prevent an unnecessary scan in the case that `@AddressCode IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks it works Simply great :)  Initially i missed that () in where so was messed up and i fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `CASE` improperly in this case (comparing with null). The right way is

```
CASE
  WHEN @AddressCode IS NULL THEN Addresses.AddressCode
  ELSE  @AddressCode
 END
```

The problem with your query is that `CASE a WHEN b THEN c...` tests if `a=b` which turns into `FALSE`(`NULL`) if one of the operands is null.
Another question is if you really need `CASE` here...